# Retrieving field params field in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have been trying to analyze this problem very closely but I am still yet to find a good way to approach it. (Hope my explanation is good enough)

So I have three models [user, status and milestone]
the status model belongs to the user model
The milestone model belongs to  status model and also to the user model through the status model

Okay so I want to tie each milestone to a model by doing something like (milestone.build_status, this is pretty easy from the CLI, I have tested and tried it, and it works as expected.)

So the big issue I am having is on the web page. I am displaying all the statuses (I have already handled cases when the user enter a status) to user with a corresponding text field where they can enter their milestone, well when I do I post I can only get the params of the text field that was supplied (duh! isnt that obvious).

My question would be what are some possible approaches that I can use to figure which particular status that the user entered the milestone for.

Comment: I didn't understand what you need. Can you post some of your code? The problem is on the form?

Comment: Could you post the relevant view code for your form? It's not clear how the form is set up. One form per status or one form with a field for each status? How are the fields named/generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be looking for [Active Record Nested Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

This will allow your forms for your object of the `User` model to also accept input for its associated `Status` and/or `Milestone` objects for creating and updating each associated records all in one transaction.